# Create "Raised" or Shadow effect on TouchableOpacity: React Native

Tags: react-native, button, styling, touchableopacity

I use `react-native-elements`, and they make it easy to make an actual button appear "raised", or shadowed. I want to duplicate this look for `TouchableOpacity`.

Here's an example of the "raised buttons" with `react-native-elements`.
[image: Raised button example]

It is subtle, but noticeably makes a nice impact.
How would you go about mimicking this effect with `TouchableOpacity`?

And yes, I've gone through the docs. If I missed anything, please point it out... but I don't think anything is there to accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: Use `elevation` on `TouchableOpacity` style

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can add the following styles to your `TouchableOpacity` to make it raised.

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} />

  button: {
    shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .4)', // IOS
    shadowOffset: { height: 1, width: 1 }, // IOS
    shadowOpacity: 1, // IOS
    shadowRadius: 1, //IOS
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    elevation: 2, // Android
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
```

*You can read more about them here.*

[**IOS Specific Props**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html)

[**Android Specific Props**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping#Elevation)